# IDLE settings change, comment key change

Tags: python, python-idle

this is not a programming question but a question about the IDLE. Is it possible to change the comment block key from '#' to something else?

here is the part that is not going to work:

```
    array = []
    y = array.append(str(words2)) <-- another part of the program
    Hash = y.count(#) <-- part that won't work
    print("There are", Hash, "#'s")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that isn't specific to IDLE that is part of the language.

EDIT: I'm pretty sure you want to use

`y.count('#')  # note the quotes`

Remember one of the strengths of Python is portability. Writing a program that would only work with your custom version of the interpreter would be removing the strengths of the language.

As a rule of thumb anytime you find yourself thinking that solution is to rewrite part of the language you might be heading in the wrong direction.

You need to call count on the string not the list:

```
array = []
    y = array.append(str(words2)) <-- another part of the program
    Hash = y[0].count('#')  # note the quotes and calling count on an element of the list not the whole list 
    print("There are", Hash, "#'s")
```

with output:

```
>>> l = []
>>> l.append('#$%^&###%$^^')
>>> l
['#$%^&###%$^^']
>>> l.count('#')
0
>>> l[0].count('#')
4
```

`count` is looking for an exact match and `'#$%^&###%$^^'` != `'#'`. You can use it on a list like so:

```
>>> l =[]
>>> l.append('#')
>>> l.append('?')
>>> l.append('#')
>>> l.append('<')
>>> l.count('#')
2
```

Comment: is there anyway to change that part of the programming then? I need it changing for a decoder program I am making

Comment: Python is open source but if you are contemplating rewriting the language you might be doing something wrong in your code.

Comment: I just need that one part of the program changing easily (will also need to do it at school as well where admin has blocked everything)

Comment: I don't think you do to be honest. Can you show us some of the code you are having a problem with?

Comment: @IanAuld I need one part of the language changing so that my program will work else it will be commenting a part of my program out

Comment: Why do you have a line starting with `#` that contains code?

Comment: I have tried this solution but it didn't work as the array has symbols in it that when printed look like this ['#$%^&###%$^^'] and list(array) won't work either